# explorer.exe crashes after AV Security Suite removal

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, malware

Hai!

Just removed the AV Security Suite using [the guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV_Security_Suite#Developers) provided on Wikipedia. Now, explorer.exe crashes at random all the time. Wat do?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall IE from scratch?

Comment: r0ca: I don't know if that's possible in 7.  Also, while they share some elements, explorer.exe is seperate from IE.

Comment: HOOO!!! Explorer, sorry, I read iexplore.exe! I would definitely reinstall from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

Boot your windows CD and select "Repair".

Comment: This is probably the best way to resolve any issues left over after removing nasty scareware.

Answer (score 0):

If all that is happening is that Explorer crashes as opposed to more serious issues like a BSOD, then what is likely happening is that a residual shell-extension (or it’s registry entry) is causing trouble.

You can weed it out by:

1. Run [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)
2. Select both *Options->Hide** options
3. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. Click the *Explorer* tab

No look through the list and see if the *Image Path* column for any are flagged as **File not found**. You can click the check-box next to it to disable it and optionally delete it.

If you are not sure about any questionable entries, you can look it up (<kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>) or ask.

You can also use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to examine the installed shell-extensions, but it does not 
flag missing files, so you’ll have to check them manually. Make sure to select the options in the *Options* menu to help reduce the clutter.